# Acessing Tensorboard on AzureML during training

Tags: tensorboard, azure-machine-learning-service

How to use view Tensorboard during an AzureML training run on in the Cloud.

Followed this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-monitor-tensorboard#launch-tensorboard

```py
from azureml.tensorboard import Tensorboard

tb = Tensorboard([run])

# If successful, start() returns a string with the URI of the instance.
tb.start()

# After your job completes, be sure to stop() the streaming otherwise it will continue to run. 
tb.stop()
```

The logs contains the url `http://localhost:6006/` printed by the `tb.start()` statement.
This is somehow silly as it runs in the cloud.

How to get the full url to the node in the cluster where Tensorboard was launched?